# Restore Database of deleted Domain -Parallels

Tags: backup, database

I accidentally deleted a domain from parallels plesk.Is it possible to restore the database related to the domain

Comment: I don't know.  Do you have backups of the database?

Comment: unfortunately the backup are too outdated taken before 6 months

Comment: @RohitS Then you can restore an outdated, 6+ month old copy of the database.... In the future you will be more diligent about backups and restore tests, yes?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry.  This monday isn't shaping up for you, is it? Well, the good thing is I'm not at work today.. The bad thing is that, that doesn't help you, and without a recent backup, you're kinda stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can restore whatever you have backups of - nothing more.
Plesk is not a magic wand - it can't make data come back from "deleted".

Per your comments all you have are old backups (from more than 6 months ago), therefore what you can restore is the old data (from more than 6 months ago).

When you have completed that restore (and rebuilt/replayed your changes on top of it) I strongly suggest you take a look at [the many questions/answers about backup strategies](https://serverfault.com/search?q=backup+strategy) on Server Fault -- Implementing a proper, regularly-tested backup and restore policy should be your #2 priority, immediately after "Fix the site that just got blown away".